# Diagnosing Segment Fault of pthread mutex

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have a system which segfaulted on an acquire of a custom thread mutex object. (this custom thread mutex is a wrapper so it can run on multiple operating systems, in this case though, it is executing linux).

Unfortunately I have struggled to recreate this seg fault on the system. It is a linux based system and I know the segment fault occurred somewhere within the 'acq' method. Based on my crash file (core dump), I did not have symbols loaded into my build, but I am able to see the backtrace of the crash, and I was able to see the last method called was the **'acq'** method.

Here is some simplified code of that thread mutex implementation. I don't think the embedded linux system was running out of memory (as we have profiled the system before and we barely ever get above 10% capacity, mostly even less). Usually when I see a segment fault I think pointers or bad array access, but a lot of this code seems to be safe with pointers and simple just call pthread methods.

I'm not overly familiar with pthreads, but is there anywhere in this implementation where you'd see a potential for a segment fault? I realize this could be like looking for a needle in a haystack, but I am trying to exercise every option.

```
struct mutexData {
  pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;
}

ThreadMutex::ThreadMutex(){
  m_data = nullptr;
}

// last function call before segment fault?
void ThreadMutex::acq(void)
{
  if (m_data == nullptr) {
    // create mutex
    m_data = new mutexData;

     pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
    
     pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
     pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP);
     pthread_mutex_init(&m_data->m_mutex, &mattr);
  }

  switch (pthread_mutex_lock (&m_data->m_mutex)) 
  {
   case 0:
    break
   case EINVAL:
    throw exception;
   default:
    throw exception;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

My goal is to try to reproduce this error again on the system (it seems to happen very sparingly) to understand why and fix the issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thread 1 enters `acq` with `m_data` null, and progresses till just after the `new` then gets suspended. Thread 2 comes along, sees `m_data` not null and... What happens next?

Comment: And the fix is to create the mutex before creating the threads.

Comment: @Mat great point! do you see any other vulnerabilities?

Comment: Note: There is probably no need to dynamically allocate the `mutexData`. If `m_data` is `mutexData m_data;` instead of `mutexData * m_data;` and it's initialized in the `ThreadMutex` constructor, many problems, including this one, will just fall away. You'll still have to observe the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), though. Sucks to accidentally copy a mutex.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. @user4581301
I made a change to just not dynamically allocate it, and i create the mutex in the constructor. Hopefully that fixes it.. trying to reproduce it to verify that it fixed it. Do you see any other vulnerabilites? theres noway pthread isn't implimented correctly.. i'm sure SO much runs on that.. there really isn't a lot of logic.. feels like that has to be it

Comment: also thank you to @Mat as well! it wouldn't let me include more than 1 at in the original comment today

Comment: @ikegami Thank you! I really appreciate the help